# How to simplify complex Trigonometric expression in mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry, expression-form

The expression which I need to simplify in mathematica into simplest form

```
Cos[\[Theta]14]]^3 Sin[\[Theta]13]^2 Sin[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]24] Exp[-i (\[Delta]14 + \[Delta]24 + 2\[Delta]13)] - Sin[\[Theta]14]]^2 Cos[\[Theta]14]] Sin[\[Theta]13]] Exp[-i (\[Delta]13 + 2\[Delta]14)] (Cos[\[Theta]24] Sin[\[Theta]23] Cos[\[Theta]13] -Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]24] Exp[i(\[Delta]14 - \[Delta]24 - \[Delta]13)]
```

On Calculating manually it is simplified into

```
Cos[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]13]^2 Sin[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]24] Exp[-i (\[Delta]14 +\[Delta]24 + 2\[Delta]13)] - Sin[\[Theta]14]^2 Cos[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]13] Cos[\[Theta]13] Cos[\[Theta]24] Sin[\[Theta]23] Exp[-i (\[Delta]13 + 2\[Delta]14)]
```

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code instead of LaTeX code.

Comment: I've given the exact mathematica code using which I need to simplify the expression into the simplest form possible.

Comment: it is a good idea to copy your own code back to your notebook to verify it is correct. If you do that, you will see it is not valid code. To paste code here, best to use  the `InputForm` version of it.  Your code as shown does not parse. Try it yourself and see.  This is what it looks like ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peAf7.png)  also, best to avoid using subscripted variables.

Comment: In addition to what Nasser said, you are using invalid syntax. `Cos^2[x]` does not mean what you think it does (in fact it's meaningless). Use `Cos[x]^2`.  Please edit the question, correct these mistakes, and show [a complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/) of an attempt to simplify an expression. The example should include the original expression in correct syntax, the command you used for simplification, the output you obtain, and the output you want to obtain instead.

Comment: You may want to go through an introductory tutorial to learn the basic syntax: https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/

Comment: I'am finding it difficult to write the expression in MSE. Sorry for the wrong codes. Edited the codes. Now you may see ones.

Comment: The code is still wrong.

Comment: You did not provide all the information I asked for. The code you did provide is still invalid, as you can check yourself by pasting it into a Mathematica notebook and trying to evaluate it. BTW `i` does not represent the imaginary unit in Mathematica—`I` does.

Comment: "I'am finding it difficult to write the expression in MSE." Don't type it directly here.  Instead, copy it from your notebook and paste it into the edit box here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an answer. I tried to correct the errors in your code. After that the initial expression is

```
expr1 = Cos[\[Theta]14]^3 Sin[\[Theta]13]^2 Sin[\[Theta]14] Sin[\
\[Theta]24] Exp[-i (\[Delta]14 + \[Delta]24 + 2 \[Delta]13)] - 
  Sin[\[Theta]14]^2 Cos[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]13] Exp[-i \
(\[Delta]13 + 
       2 \[Delta]14)] (Cos[\[Theta]24] Sin[\[Theta]23] \
Cos[\[Theta]13] - 
     Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]24] Exp[-i (\[Delta]14 - \[Delta]24 \
- \[Delta]13)]);
```

The final expression you have simplified manually is

```
expr2=Cos[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]13]^2 Sin[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]24] \
Exp[-i (\[Delta]14 + \[Delta]24 + 2 \[Delta]13)] - 
 Sin[\[Theta]14]^2 Cos[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]13] Cos[\[Theta]13] \
Cos[\[Theta]24] Sin[\[Theta]23] Exp[-i (\[Delta]13 + 2 \[Delta]14)];
```

If I corrected everything right it is not difficult to make sure that these two expressions are not equal to one another:

```
expr1 - expr2 // FullSimplify

(*  E^(-i (2 \[Delta]13 + 4 \[Delta]14 + \[Delta]24))
  Cos[\[Theta]14] Sin[\[Theta]13]^2 Sin[\[Theta]14]^2 (E^(
   i (2 \[Delta]13 + \[Delta]14 + 2 \[Delta]24)) - 
   E^(3 i \[Delta]14) Sin[\[Theta]14]) Sin[\[Theta]24]  *)
```

To be absolutely sure let us make an arbitrary substitution

```
(expr1 - expr2 // 
   FullSimplify) /. {\[Theta]14 -> \[Pi]/4, \[Theta]24 -> \[Pi]/
    4, \[Theta]13 -> \[Pi]/4, \[Theta]23 -> 0, \[Delta]13 -> 
   0, \[Delta]14 -> 0, \[Delta]24 -> 0}

(*  1/8 (1 - 1/Sqrt[2])  *)
```

Again, if I did not introduce something wrong during the correction of your code, my calculations demonstrate that your hand-made simplification contains an error.

On my side, I tried to simplify your expression (In my correction, of course). It is possible to rewrite it in several other forms, which find to be not much simpler than the initial one.